# segmentation fault while running shellcode

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am experimenting with shellcode before digging deep into it so I came across an example from the shellcoders handbook. The example is the following:

```
char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x4
\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69
\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

int main() {

int *ret;
ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
(*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

the shellcode is supposed to spawn a shell. However I get a segmentation fault error.
I compiled the program using `gcc` compiler with `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack` options. I took a quick look at the `readelf` command and it was clear that the stack is executable

```
 GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RWE 0x4
```

Comment: Backticks are used to quote code, not to add emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

`ret` is a pointer and it not pointing to any memory location when you declare it.
Later you are trying to assign some value to it by adding 2 to the location the pointer is pointing to.(Which is contradictory statement )

```
ret = (int *)&ret + 2;/* Which is wrong */
```

Comment: True. Its clear now. Thats why you always need someone else to read what you write, because he will simply see your mistakes that you just overlook every time you re-read the code.

Comment: I downvoted this answer. The question's code is intended overwrite the return address with the address of `shellcode`; it is not accidental undefined behaviour. (And obviously it's not supposed to be portable or standard-conforming C)

Comment: @immibis would you like to answer the question then ?

Comment: @T-D We can't convince everyone I hope I answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I compile following code using "gcc filename.cpp" command. Ti's compiled without error.I hope this will help you to solve your doubt.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x4\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

int main() {

int *ret;
ret = (int *) ret + 2; //I don't know why you had written this
ret = (int *)shellcode;

}
```